# How do I create a table function for my program?

Tags: python-3.5, create-function

I want to make a function which pulls the data from the code and creates a table out of it:

```
 if mode_choice ==1 or 2:
    def main():
        pv= float(input("Enter the principle amount: "))
        interest = float(input("Enter the interest rate (in perecent): "))
        term = int(input("Enter the term (in months): "))
        interest = interest / 12 / 100

        payment = (interest * pv) / (1-(1 + interest)**-term)


    main()
```

Comment: You need need to tell us which language you are working with!

Comment: I'm working in python 3.5.